# QML-Window disappears from windows-taskbar after call of hide() and show()

Tags: window, qml, hide, show

I would like to hide a window and afterwards show it again without loosing it from Windows-Taskbar.

```
Item{
ExampleItem{
 id: exampleWindow
}
```

Now I want to call from anywhere:

```
exampleWindow.hide()
```

It will disappear from screen and taskbar

At a later time I want to be able to call

```
exampleWindow.show()
```

but if I do so, the window will be on screen again, but not connectetd to my windows-taskbar. Is there any solution for this issue? As the item is still active in the background I don't understand why it looses its connection on windowstaskbar.

(When minimizing this window, it will go to the bottom of the screen only showing the window-buttons)

EDIT: See Picture: I want the window back in this group after called hide() and then show() again.
[image]

EDIT2: Sorry I can't reproduce the status of my project in an small example. For any reason in my taskbar will only be shown one window even though I created an extra window which will be shown on the desktop. But this is some kind of the same question. How do I get an extra window from mainApplication to be shown in the windowstaskbar

EDIT3:
If you take main.qml like this:

```
    import QtQuick 2.5
    import QtQuick.Window 2.2
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

    ApplicationWindow {
        visible: true
        width: 640
        height: 480
        title: "Hello World"

        ExampleWindow {
            id: exWin
        }
    }
```

and put your code (from answer) to ExampleWindow.qml

```
Window {
    id: root
    color: 'steelblue'
    visible: true
    width: 1024
    height: 800

     Timer {
        id: tim
        interval: 1000
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: root.visible = !root.visible
    }
}
```

than you get exactly my problem.
When starting the application I will have two windows shown in my Windows10-Taskbar (multiple(two) windows stacked in a group). If the timer ran out and hides the window it has gone from screen and from Windows-Taskbar(one window, no group)
When the timer fires again. The window will be shown again but it will never show up in the taskbar group again. And I can't reach the window by pressing Windows+Tab...

Comment: Your code is no working example. How can I help you?

Comment: I thought it would be answerable without a running example. But I can build an example for this...

Comment: I will try to answer it, but I can only assume...

Comment: So you want to minimize the Window to the TaskBar?

Comment: No I want to use the hide-Function to completely hide the window (from screen and Windows-Taskbar). Then when I call show-Function I want to see the window again(this works like expected) AND I want it back in the windowsTaskbar, to select it from there.

Comment: I do not have a Windows machine at hand right now, but when I tested my code today on Windows, it worked just as described right now - from my point of view. What is the exact *behavioral* difference you want to achieve, from the behavior of my code-snippet down there? A small remark to your screenshot: You have multiple windows open. They get stacked by the Taskbar. You can change that behavior in the Windows settings. To create multiple windows, the engine (in main.cpp) can load multiple files or one file multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have a running example of yours, I can only guess, what you want.
Does this help you/work as expected?

```
Window {
    id: root
    color: 'steelblue'
    visible: true
    width: 1024
    height: 800

    Timer {
        id: tim
        interval: 1000
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: root.visible = !root.visible
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not what I ment. Sorry for wasting your time on this. I am struggeling with creating a simple example right now. I will try to do this in the evening...

Comment: OK, if you write main.qml like this: